# Load a Flickr tree as html recursive in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, flickr

I'm currently trying to render a tree of Flickr Collections and Sets as HTML from C#. I'm using the Flickr.NET library to a list of all my collections with their childcollections and sets.

What I need to do is to render this tree as a HTML tree using nested unordered lists and I'm thinking of a recursive solution since a Collection can hold one or more sets and also hold child collections which again can hold sets and collections.

What I have right now is a list of all the root collections, their childcollections and their sets. So i.e. my Flickr tree looks like this:

- Collection (this collection is in my list as an object itself)

  - Collection

    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
  - Collection

    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
- Collection (this collection is in my list as an object itself)

  - Collection

    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
  - Collection

    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2
    - Set

      - Photo1
      - Photo2

And basically it could looks a hundred more ways since editors will eventually create a number more Collections within collections and sets within sets.

So, for every collection and set, I need a new nested unordered list.

I know this is quite complex, but nonetheless, it would be great to have an algorithm to render the tree as HTML. I've just become a tad too rusty when it comes to recursive algorithms :-/

I guess my basecase here is if the current collection doesn't have any childcollections and doesn't have any, then I can stop the recursive method?

Any help/hint on this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance.

All the best,

Bo

**SOLUTION**

I broke down the algorithms in four steps:

```
private void LoadFlickrTreeRecursive()
    {
        foreach (var collection in allCollections)
        {
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<ul class='collection'>");
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<li>" + collection.Title + "</li>");
            if (collection.Sets.Count > 0)
                RenderFlickPhotoSet(collection.Sets);

            if (collection.Collections.Count > 0)                
                RenderFlickrCollectionRecursive(collection.Collections);                    

            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("</ul>");
        }
    }

    private void RenderFlickPhotoSet(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<CollectionSet> sets)
    {
        foreach (var set in sets)
        {
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<ul class='set'>");
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<li>" + set.Title + "</li>");
            var photos = flickr.PhotosetsGetPhotos(set.SetId);
            if (photos.Count > 0)
            {
                flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<ul class='photos'>");
                foreach (var photo in photos)
                {
                    flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<li>" + photo.Title + "</li>");
                }
                flickrTreeMarkup.Append("</ul>");
            }
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("</ul>");                 
        }
    }

    private void RenderFlickrCollectionRecursive(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Collection> collections)
    {
        foreach (var collection in collections)
        {
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<ul class='collection'>");
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("<li>" + collection.Title + "</li>");
            RenderFlickPhotoSet(collection.Sets);
            if (collection.Collections.Count > 0)
            {                    
                RenderFlickrCollectionRecursive(collection.Collections);                    
            }
            flickrTreeMarkup.Append("</ul>");                
        }            
    }
```

Works like a charm :-)

However, if anyone know of a better way than this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: can you show exactly what you want... like the way you have showed what you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm should work with a TreeView control:

```
function rec(Collection c, TreeNode n)
{
   TreeNode me = new TreeNode();
   n.ChildNodes.Add(me);
   for each collection v in c:
       rec(v, me)
   for each set s in c:
       AddSet(s, me)
}
```

Comment: Hi Desolator, thanks for your input :-) I should've mentioned that I needed the tree to be rendered on a webpage- sorry about that.

Comment: @bomortensen So how do you want it to be "on web page"? Do you want to view it on the page like above illustration?

Comment: yes, exactly :) simply a treeview with plus/minus on Collections and Sets. Got the HTML rendered now, just need the javascript to make it behave like an actual tree.

Comment: @bomortensen If you want to use javasript then tag your question with that. I recommand you to use asp.net to use TreeView control. I will edit my answer to deal with a TreeView instead of file